# Arithmetic right shift on logic (2 dimensional) signal

Tags: system-verilog, bit-shift, signed

I am trying to do a Shift Right, Arithmetic (keep sign) on the signal `in`.

When I set the value `in[0]` to `16'hbb00`, I expect `in_sign_extend[0]` to be `16'hf760` after it is signed right shifted. But, I notice that the actual result I see on `in_sign_extend[0]` is `16'h0680`.

```
localparam CHANNELS = 8;
localparam AXI_M_DATA_WIDTH = 32;

logic signed [0:CHANNELS-1]    [AXI_M_DATA_WIDTH/2-1:0] in;
logic signed [0:CHANNELS-1]    [AXI_M_DATA_WIDTH/2-1:0] in_sign_extend;

assign in_sign_extend[0] = (in[0] >>> 3);
```

I am trying to understand if the `in` is actually correctly signed. Or am I missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part select of a packed array is always unsigned, even when selecting the entire array. Only the variable as a whole reference (`in`) is *signed*. You can change your code to

```
assign in_sign_extend[0] = (signed'(in[0]) >>> 3);
```

Or you might prefer to use an unpacked array

```
logic signed [AXI_M_DATA_WIDTH/2-1:0] in[CHANNELS];
logic signed [AXI_M_DATA_WIDTH/2-1:0] in_sign_extend[CHANNELS];

assign in_sign_extend[0] = (in[0] >>> 3);
```